# Getting multiple data from multiple select boxes'

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got next situation:

I have multiple select boxes (that can select multiple choices) and i need that in php to be processed.

A code is next:

```html
<select name="selectusers[]"  multiple>
 <option value="1">John</option>
 <option value="2">Smith</option>
</select>
<select name="selectusers[]"  multiple>
 <option value="1">John</option>
 <option value="2">Smith</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

So now, in PHP I do the general `foreach`

```
<?php
    foreach($select_users as $users){
        ...
    }
?>
```

But each time I do foreach loop, and i print_r($select_users); inside of foreach, it gives me same result like:

```
Array([0]=>Array([0]=>30)[1]=>Array([0]=>33))
Array([0]=>Array([0]=>30)[1]=>Array([0]=>33))
```

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: that form doesn't make sense, there's two select boxes with both multiple attributes why not just one select box, you could select both `John` and `Smith` selections in one select box anyway

Comment: Because I'm appending more selecting boxes combined with text box (named title) and every title have it's users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the name of your select:

```html
<select name="selectusers[]"  multiple>
 <option value="1">John</option>
 <option value="2">Smith</option>
</select>
<select name="selectusers2[]"  multiple>
 <option value="1">John</option>
 <option value="2">Smith</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

Try this.

Comment: Is it anyhow possible to use same name?

Comment: Thank you, I've made it like that somehow.